# camel health check for producerTemplate

Tags: apache-camel, spring-boot-actuator, spring-camel

I would like to add health check for the camel producerTemplate which is used to publish message to kafka. I wonder if it's possible by adding configurations on application.yml file, something like below.

```
camel:
  health:
    enabled: true
    producersEnabled: true
```

so for now, I can see status, components { camelHealth{j,
ms {}, discoveryComposite {discovery client not initialized}, diskspace {}, ping {}, refreshScope {}

I use camel-spring-boot-starter, camel-kafka, camel-jms, spring-boot-starter-actuator, spring-boot-starter-web along with others.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any progress on this?